# How to disable jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a strange task, I need two types of popup windows for my site,
the first one is a normal popup, for desktop version of site
and another one is for mobile version of site

the question is: is it possible to enable jquery.mobile once I show popup for mobile version
and disable jquery mobile once I close the popup ?

(For your information: I do not use an iframe for my popups)

I found strange way how to enable jquery.mobile once I need it
but in this case I can't disable jquery.mobile

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;  
});
setTimeout(function(){
  $.mobile.initializePage();// run jquery.mobile in 15 seconds for example
},15000);
```

Comment: Alas, there is no counterpart to `initializePage()` (yet). Once a document is augmented, it stays that way. You could write it yourself, but you would have to revert all the modifications `initializePage()` performed on the DOM, which will probably not be easy.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi it isn't what I'm looking for, would be great to find some normal way in order to have ability to use next new version of jquery.mobile, I do not want to fix my method with each new version (:

Comment: That's understandable. Do you only want to remove styling, as Jasper's answer implements, or do you want to undo the widgets too?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi I want to back normal page as it was before I enabled jquery.mobile, I wanna be sure everything on page will works fine

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the CSS of jQuery Mobile to add a "flag" so it only applies to elements within a specific container.

Here is a sample jQuery Mobile CSS rule declaration (just the selector):

```
.ui-li-has-arrow .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit
```

If you change this to:

```
.my-custom-class .ui-li-has-arrow .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit
```

Then the CSS will only be applied to elements within an element with the `my-custom-class` class. This means that you can have a regularly styled page most of the time, but when you want to use jQuery Mobile styles you just have to show your dialog in a container with the `my-custom-class` (or whatever you want to name your class).

Comment: I do not want to customize jquery.mobile's files, in this case I will not able to get next new version of jquery.mobile, I would need to customize it again, to test it again